# Unit tests is to test controller method that mocked service method or to test service method directly?

Tags: spring, web-services, rest, unit-testing, mocking

Context : Spring Boot, RESTful web services.

I wrote a web service for Survey project,

```
@RestController
public class SurveyEndpoint {

   @Autowired
   private SurveyService surveyService;

   @RequestMapping(value="surveys/{surveyId}/questions/{questionId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
   public QuestionEntity getQuestions(@PathVariable String surveyId, @PathVariable String questionId){
            return surveyService.retrieveQuestionById(surveyId, questionId);
}
```

Below is Component class:

```
@Component
public class SurveyService {

    public QuestionEntity retrieveQuestionById(String surveyId, String questionId) {

            //Code for retrieving question
        }
```

I wrote a unit test, that test directly a component method as follow:

```
public class SurveyServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    SurveyService surveyService;

    @Test
    public void testRetrieveQuestionById() {

        QuestionEntity questions = surveyService.retrieveQuestionById("Survey1", "Question1");

        assertEquals("Question1", questions.getQuestionId());
    }
```

other way is testing controller method directly, like below:

```
@Test
    public void testRetrieveQuestionById() throws Exception {
        QuestionEntity mockQuestion = new QuestionEntity("Question1",
                "Largest Country in the World", "Russia", Arrays.asList(
                        "India", "Russia", "United States", "China"));

        Mockito.when(
                surveyService.retrieveQuestionById(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(mockQuestion);

        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/surveys/Survey1/questions/Question1").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();

        String expected = "{id:Question1,description:Largest Country in the World,correctAnswer:Russia}";

        JSONAssert.assertEquals(expected, result.getResponse()
                .getContentAsString(), false);

        // Assert
    }
}
```

So from above,

1. A test for service method directly
2. A test that test controller method by mocking service methods

Which one right way to write Unit test ?

Answer (score 0):

These are two different unit tests for two different component so there isn't a unit test better than another.